# How to set-up wagtail pages

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield, wagtail-admin, wagtail-snippet

I am trying to configure a django project that uses the wagtail CMS to display the templates(the templates is already in the file) on the frontend but since it is my first time working with wagtail, I am having issues and don't know where to head to. I have checked some external sources like YouTube perhaps I will get any illustration of such but I don't seem to get any.

The whole project structure is shown below and this shows that the whole templates and html files are intact but I don't know how to set it up.

If I run the program using the `python manage.py runserver`, I get the project running and after opening the localhost:8000 on the browser, I only get a blank screen.

The url.py file of the main project is show below:

```
# django imports
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
# wagtail imports
from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail.core import urls as wagtail_urls
from wagtail.documents import urls as wagtaildocuments_urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^django-admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    url(r'^robots\.txt$', TemplateView.as_view(
        template_name='robots.txt', content_type='text/plain'
    )),
    url(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocuments_urls)),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),
)
```

The project structure:

```
│   manage.py
│
├───about
│   │   apps.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   translation.py
│   │   __init__.py
│
├───except_wagtail
│   │   abstract_models.py
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   blocks.py
│   │   context_processors.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   settings.py
│   │   sitemap.py
│   │   translation.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   wagtail_hooks.py
│   │   wsgi.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───templates
│   │   │   404.html
│   │   │   500.html
│   │   │   base.html
│   │   │   base_new.html
│   │   │   robots.txt
│   │   │   sitemap.xml
│   │   │
│   │   ├───about
│   │   │       about_page.html
│   │   │       contact_page.html
│   │   │       event_calendar_page.html
│   │   │       generic_page.html
│   │   │       privacy_page.html
│   │   │       resources_page.html
│   │   │
│   │   ├───index
│   │   │       home_page.html
│   │   │
│   │   ├───knowledge
│   │   │       article_page.html
│   │   │       knowledge_page.html
│   │   │
│   │   ├───news
│   │   │       news_index_page.html
│   │   │       news_page.html
│   │   │
│   │   ├───people
│   │   │       people_page.html
│   │   │       profile_page.html
│   │   │
│   │   ├───projects
│   │   │       project_index_page.html
│   │   │       project_page.html
│   │   │
│   │   ├───search
│   │   │       search.html
│   │   │
│   │   ├───services
│   │   │       service_index_page.html
│   │   │       service_page.html
│   │   │       service_pillar_page.html
│   │   │       working_area_page.html
│   │   │
│   │   ├───_blocks
│   │   │       blockquote.html
│   │   │       carousel_block.html
│   │   │       lightbox_block.html
│   │   │       linked_asset_block.html
│   │   │       paragraph_block.html
│   │   │       people_list_block.html
│   │   │       related_assets_block.html
│   │   │       spacer_block.html
│   │   │
│   │   ├───_includes
│   │   │   │   card.html
│   │   │   │   card_new.html
│   │   │   │   card_old.html
│   │   │   │   card_people.html
│   │   │   │   card_video.html
│   │   │   │   card_with_col.html
│   │   │   │   index_item_search.html
│   │   │   │   index_item_specific_cards.html
│   │   │   │   ld_article.html
│   │   │   │   ld_article.json
│   │   │   │   ld_organization.html
│   │   │   │   ld_organization.json
│
├───index
│   │   apps.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   translation.py
│   │   __init__.py
│
├───knowledge
│   │   apps.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   translation.py
│   │   __init__.py
│
├───news
│   │   apps.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   translation.py
│   │   __init__.py
│
├───people
│   │   apps.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   translation.py
│   │   __init__.py
│
├───projects
│   │   apps.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   translation.py
│   │   __init__.py
│
├───search
│   │   apps.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   translation.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│
└───services
    │   apps.py
    │   models.py
    │   translation.py
    │   __init__.py
```

Comment: This is really too vague for anyone to help. I suggest working through the [tutorial](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html) first. That will show you how Wagtail is meant to work, and from there you'll be able to work out the next steps to troubleshoot this site: can you log in to the admin? Is there a homepage set up? If so, where does the 'view live' link take you? What template is that page using? If you make changes to that template, do they show up? And so on.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I will check that out and try fihure out my way.

Comment: @gasman, could you please spare me some minutes of your time over a zoom call to put me through, I watched the tutorial guide you sent me but I don't seem to understand how to go about this.

Comment: @oyerohabib - you may have already seen this but there is a Slack group if you need help where stackoverflow's Q&A format does not work. https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/wiki/Slack